# Name of 4-conductor twinned headphone wire

Tags: cables

I would like to get more serious about repairing headphones, as well as making my own extension cords ( as the ones you can buy tend to be pretty low quality, and I am tired of breaking).

The kind of cable I am looking for was the primary kind of cable used for headphones a while ago. [1] It is composed of four conductors. Sheathed in the insulation in pairs, with pairs of insulation bonded. You can split the insulation down the middle and and have two pairs of insulted wired ( each pair having two conductors )go to each speaker separately.

What is this cable called? ( A link to some such cable would be useful. )

[1] It seems that modern headphones mostly use three conductor cable. Or it seems that way to me. Possibly because I use behind the neck type headphones.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I thought that would be an easy search. Then it wasn't. Then I was really curious.

Looks like the cable you are referring to is called **Dual-Pair Zip-Cord** From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip-cord), zip cord:

> refers to two or more electrical conductors held together by an insulating jacket that can be easily separated simply by pulling apart.

Searching "double-pair" or "dual-pair" seems to bring up the cable you are referring to. Belden comes up a lot as the manufacturer.

Example catalog (ctrl-f "zip"):

http://www.belden.com/products/catalogs/mastercatalog/brilliance/upload/19Broadcast_Cables.pdf

An example of a store listing:

http://www.interstatewire.com/double-pair-cable-1802b-z4b1000.html

Though a lot of the examples I'm seeing are shielded, twisted pairs. I'm not sure where the cheap, old headphone cables are hiding. You may want to invest in a bunch of heat shrink and a good heat gun for your uneven lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Years ago I used to use a cable similar to what you are describing.  We called it Microphone cable and it had a rubber EPDM outer jacket.  The individual conductors were also insulated with Rubber EPDM and the individual conductors were bonded to each other as you describe.

The closest I could come in a search has Polyethylene insulation: http://www.alliedelec.com/search/productdetail.aspx?SKU=70005399

To get a list of selections, go onto any electronic supply website and search for Microphone or Musical Instrument cable.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a source of that twin-ZIP cord in bulk format but I can tell you where to get it.

I regularly repair professional headphones.  AKG is one supplier who makes dual-ear headphones used in broadcast and recording.  The cords for the headphones is a wear item and replacements are readily available.

Same for most other suppliers of professional headphones / headsets.  Sennheiser, Sony, Beyer-Dynamic, AKG are some of the headphones that I work with regularly.  Wear items are readily available as replacement parts.

Although these replacement parts may cost more than other sources, the headset wire is designed for continuous, heavy-duty use and it lasts a long time.  Much better quality than inexpensive consumer stuff.